# How am I able to return value in PHP (html table)

Tags: php

Alright guys, I'll try to explain it as best as I can, I'm pretty new to this stuff so forgive me if I make some little mistakes!

so I got a small problem, I want to make a variable that if I give it a number 1, 2, 3 it ahs to return an other value to my table. Like, If I give my variable (in this case) $Jeffgender "1" it has to give the output "Male" in the .

PHP variables in index.php

```
$Jeffgender = new gender("1");
$Paddygender = new gender("1");
$Helengender = new gender("2");
```

**table in index.php**

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"; 
echo "Gender";
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $Jeffgender;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $Paddygender;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $Helengender;
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

**class_lib.php**

```
class gender {

    function __construct($gender_name)
    {
        if ($gender_name == 1) {

            return "Male";

        } elseif ($gender_name == 2) {

            return "Female";

        } elseif ($gender_name == 3) {

            return "Unknown";

        }
    }
}
```

Hope I explained it well for you guys, if not please post questions and I'll reply within a few secs.

Comment: What is `if ($gender_name::1) {`??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Victor, I tried some codes.. I changed it back to "==", sorry for the mess up

Comment: echo $gender_name inside the constructor and see what it display

Comment: @user574632, I want my table td to return an other value when I give it the numebr 1, 2 or 3. How do I do this? surely not this way haha

Comment: @Karthick Kumar Ganesh, maybe I'm mistaking but you can use echo in a class?

Comment: put echo in function before this line     if ($gender_name==1) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like that:

```
class Gender {

      protected $gender;

      function __construct($gender_name)
      {
          $this->gender = $gender_name;
      }

      function getGender() {
          if ($this->gender == 1) {
              return "Male";
          }
          elseif ($this->gender == 2)
          {
              return "Female";
          }
          elseif ($this->gender == 3)
          {
              return "Unknown";
          }
      }
  }

    $Jeffgender = new Gender(1);

    $Paddygender = new Gender(2);

    $Helengender = new Gender(3);

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>"; 
   echo "Gender";
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo $Jeffgender->getGender();
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo $Paddygender->getGender();
   echo "</td>";

   echo "<td>";
   echo $Helengender->getGender();
   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped

Answer (score 2):

Constructor does not return values. Try this:

```
class gender {

    private $sex;

    function __construct($gender_name)
    {
        if ($gender_name == 1) {

            $this->sex = "Male";

        } elseif ($gender_name == 2) {

            $this->sex = "Female";

        } elseif ($gender_name == 3) {

            $this->sex = "Unknown";

        }
    }

    public function __toString() {

        return (string)$this->sex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some clarification first: Your construct method shouldn't return anything. It is made to return a new Object of the type implicitly.

First: Change the type of the arguments. You're putting in `"1"`, a string, but then later you check for `1`, an integer. So you want your calls like that: `new gender(1)`.

Second: When you want to echo an object (or a string representation of that object to be precise) there is another magic method called `__toString()`. Whenever your object is used in a string context (like concatenation or printing) this method will implicitly be called, returning a string for representing your object.

Your new class may look like that:

```
class gender {
    private $gender_name;
    function __construct($gender_name)
    {
        $this->gender_name = $gender_name;
    }

    function __toString() {
        if ($gender_name == 1) {
            return "Male";
        }
        elseif ($gender_name == 2)
        {
            return "Female";
        }
        elseif ($gender_name == 3)
        {
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using "" when calling the class, but within the class checking for integers.

```
"2" is different to 2
```

Try making them match and see if it works.

Comment: This would only matter if he compares it with ===

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting slightly confusing with accessing properties in classes, and types.

**Just remember, constructors don't actually return a value. They return the object.**

Try this:

```
class gender {

    private $gender_name;

    function __construct($gender_name)
    {
        $this->gender = $gender_name;
    }


    public function get_gender()
    {
        if ($this->gender_name === '1' || $this->gender_name === 1) {

            return "Male";

        } elseif ($this->gender_name === '2' || $this->gender_name === 2) {

            return "Female";

        } elseif ($this->gender_name === '3' || $this->gender_name === 3) {

            return "Unknown";

        }
    }
}
```

I've added a new method called `get_gender()`.
When you create a new object, you pass the gender ID to the constructor. This constructor then sets a private property within the scope of the object.

The `get_gender()` method then allows you to retrieve the gender.

Now call it like this:

```
$a = new gender(1);
echo $a->get_gender();
```

Comment: Got this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class gender could not be converted to string in  C:\wamp\www\testt\index.php on line 99 "
echo $Jeffgender; that is

Comment: Have you written `echo $a->get_gender();` and not `echo $a;`?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple...

A constructor in OOP can't return a value. Put your code inside another function and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing won't work since you are using echo on an object of class gender.

You'll have to store $gender_name when it is passed to the constructor and use the magic method __toString() in order to print something, or implement your own method genderToString().

ie :

```
 class Gender
 {
     protected $gender_name;

     public function __construct($gender_name)
     {
         $this->gender_name = $gender_name;
     }

     public function __toString()
     {
         return $this->gender_name;
     }
 }
```

Personally, I'd rather do something like this :

```
$maleGender = new Gender(Gender::TYPE_MALE);
echo $maleGender; // prints 'Male'

class Gender
{
    const TYPE_MALE  = 1;
    const TYPE_FEMALE = 2;
    const TYPE_UNKNOWN = 3;

    protected $type;

    function __construct($type)
    {
        if (!in_array($type, array(self::TYPE_MALE, self::TYPE_FEMALE, self::TYPE_UNKNOWN)))
        {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Wrong type.');
        }

        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $string = '';
        switch ($this->type)
        {
            case self::TYPE_MALE:
                $string = 'Male';
                break;
            case self::TYPE_FEMALE:
                $string = 'Female';
                break;
            case self::TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                $string = 'Unknown';
                break;
        }

        return $string;
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

No need to create more than one instance of the class, one is enough, and its better if you created another function which return the gender string.

```
class gender {

        function __construct()
        {
        }
        function getGender($gender_num)
        {
            if ($gender_num == 1) {
                return "Male";
            }
            elseif ($gender_num == 2)
            {
                return "Female";
            }
            elseif ($gender_num == 3)
            {
                return "Unknown";
            }
        }
    }`
```

$gen = new gender();

echo $gen->getGender(1); // etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how to use contructors properly:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Constructor is used to create new object of type of the class, and the 'result' of calling the constructor would be an instance of the class object, not the string as in your case.

To use it properly in your case, I would modify class like this:

```
class gender {
    private $gender;
    function __construct($gender_name)
    {
        $this->gender = $gender_name;
    }

    function getGenderName(){
        if ($this->gender == 1) {
            return "Male";
        }
        elseif ($this->gender == 2)
        {
            return "Female";
        }
        elseif ($this->gender == 3)
        {
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Than instead of trying to print instances of this class, you should print results of a method getGenderName():

```
echo "<td>";
    echo $Jeffgender->getGenderName();
echo "</td>";
```

And do this for all your objects.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of your constructor method isn't saved anywhere.

```
$Jeffgender = new gender("1");
print_r($Jeffgender);
```

The print_r shows that $Jeffgender is an object of the class gender but has no properties. So the gender should be a static class with a function which return the text you want to have.